# Only give PS access to a specific VM?

Tags: azure

I have an VM running in Azure which I would like the client to be able to turn on/off easily. I tought this would be simple; just a PS-script that performs an startup/shutdown/dealloc. But it seems I can't generate a "Azure Publish Settings"-file that only gives access to that VM? At the moment it seems I can only control this at the subscription level?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Publish Settings file basically contains the access information for an entire Azure subscription.  It does not specify access to a specific resource (e.g. VM) but to all resources inside of a subscription. 
To limit access to a subset of resources in Azure, you should be looking at the new [role-based access (RBAC)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) functionality, which is available in the Azure preview portal and the latest Azure PowerShell cmdlets.
How it works is that you create an Azure resource group, to which you can assign roles with specific rights, and to this role you can then assign individual users.
Check the following [Azure documentation link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-rbac/) for details on how to do this.